# Cordova Request Location Accuracy Plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I want to use Cordova Request Location Accuracy Plugin in my phonegap app
i add 
in my config.xml and then i try to use  cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(); but my console throws
TypeError: cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy is undefined
What am i missing?
Thanks!!

Comment: Can you add your config.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If building locally, make sure it's installed in your project:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy
```

Or if building in cloud (e.g. Phonegap Build), make sure it's referenced in the config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" spec="*" />
```

Then make sure you wait for the `deviceready` event before referencing the plugin, because Cordova dynamically loads the JS plugin components at runtime:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request();
}, false);
```

Check the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) for platform-specifics and the [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy-example) for an illustration of usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot i was in local!